# Check if strings from a list in a text and return first longest match

Tags: python

I'm trying to design an application that binds a phrase or word to some item, for example image, and saves phrase-item pair in the database. Then it receives a text, and if it contains binded phrase, corresponding item should be returned. 
It should return only one item for the whole text, and longest substrings should take precedence.

I wrote a function, that returns expected values:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def get_item(text, bindings): 
    text = text.lower()
    matches = []
    for phrase, item in bindings:
        phrase = phrase.lower()
        index = text.find(phrase)
        if index != -1:
            matches.append((phrase, item, index))
    if matches:
        matches.sort(key=lambda x: len(x[0]), reverse=True)
        matches.sort(key=itemgetter(2))
        item_id = matches[0][1]
    else:
        item_id = None
    return item_id
```

Example:

```
bindings = [
('i', 'item1'), ('like', 'item2'), ('i like', 'item3'), ('turtles', 'item4'),
]
text = 'I like turtles!'
print(get_item(text, bindings)) # should return item3
```

But is there cleaner ways to complete such task, or faster, perhaps?

Comment: this may belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your example is returning 'item2' not 'item3'.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Text in bindings supposed to be lower too.